# how to save bidrectional entity with dto

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I have two spring boot entities MeetingSetting and MeetingTime, MeetingSetting can have multiple MeetingTimes. I am trying to save these to at the same time with the DTO structure, so I can avoid the circular reference problem when I am getting MeetingTimes. Saving partially works. MeetingSettings has a property called meetingName which is a foreign key in meetingTimes. Everything except meetingName is saved which is for some reason null, but I can not find the reason, could someone maybe look at my code and tell me what I am missing?

MeetingSetting Entity:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "meeting_settings")
@Setter
@Getter
public class MeetingsSetting implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "meeting_name", unique = true)
    private String meetingName;

    @Column(name = "meeting_url")
    private String meetingUrl;

    @Column(name = "meeting_pw")
    private String meetingPw;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "meetingName", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private Set<MeetingTime> meetingTime = new HashSet<>();
}
```

MeetingSettingDTO:

```
@Getter
@Setter
public class MeetingSettingDTO {


    private Long id;


    @NotNull
    private String meetingName;

    @NotNull
    private String meetingUrl;

    @NotNull
    private String meetingPw;

    private Set<MeetingTime> meetingTime;
}
```

MeetingTime Entity:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "meeting_times")
@Getter
@Setter
public class MeetingTime implements Serializable {

    @JsonIgnore
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "meeting_date")
    private String date;

    @Column(name = "start_time")
    private String startTime;

    @Column(name = "end_time")
    private String endTime;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "meeting_name" , referencedColumnName = "meeting_name")
    private MeetingsSetting meetingName;
}
```

MeetingTimeDTO:

```
@Getter
@Setter
public class MeetingTimeDTO {


    private Long id;

    @NotNull
    private String date;

    @NotNull
    private String startTime;
    @NotNull
    private String endTime;

    private Set<MeetingSettingDTO> meetingSettings;

}
```

And finally the controller where I am saving everything (Just save method):

```
@PostMapping("/")
    public void saveMeeting(@RequestBody MeetingSettingDTO meetingSettingDTO){
       MeetingsSetting meetingsSetting = new MeetingsSetting();
       meetingsSetting.setMeetingName(meetingSettingDTO.getMeetingName());
       meetingsSetting.setMeetingPw(meetingSettingDTO.getMeetingPw());
       meetingsSetting.setMeetingUrl(meetingSettingDTO.getMeetingUrl());
        Set<MeetingTime> meetingTimeSet = meetingSettingDTO.getMeetingTime();
        meetingsSetting.setMeetingTime(meetingTimeSet);
        meetingSettingService.saveMeeting(meetingsSetting);

    }
```

My service is just implementing a jpaRepository which takes MeetingSetting as parameter

Comment: You must explicitly set parent for each MeetingTime entity in the Set<MeetingTime>.

Comment: I did not understand what you mean sorry for my bad english not a native speaker and new to this DTO thing haha

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your `MeetingTime` entity class you have a parent:

```
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "meeting_name" , referencedColumnName = "meeting_name")
    private MeetingsSetting meetingName;
```

You have to set it explicitly for each `MeetingTime`, so add this:

```
Set<MeetingTime> meetingTimeSet = meetingSettingDTO.getMeetingTime();
meetingTimeSet.forEach(m -> m.meetingName(meetingsSetting));
```

Comment: In my save method?

Comment: It would be good to transfer the logic for converting a dto to an entity into a mapper, e.g. mapstruct. But for now try to add this code in your controller.

Comment: I tried it in my save method and it worked but if I understood you correctly I should make a mapper class and put your code as a method inside it right?

Comment: If I try to make a get request now for meetingTime I am getting the following error:
Could not write JSON: Infinite recursion (StackOverflowError); nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind

What I want is to display meetingTime with its foreign key together...

Comment: I saw an example I tried to copy it I thought I had to do it because I am doing a reference in my Entity as well to MeetingSetting. Is that wrong?

Comment: No, it's ok, you set a parent to each child

Comment: Do you know how I could fix the infinite recursion error? I have to make the foreign key meetingName visible in meetingTime response

Comment: Why you have in your ```MeetingTimeDTO``` a field ```Set<MeetingSettingDTO> meetingSettings```?; It should be simple one object and not a Set, or not?

Comment: I changed it to a simple one object but still am getting the same error

Comment: private MeetingSettingDTO meetingSettings; currently looks like this

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/233678/discussion-between-george-lvov-and-haso).